# Two way Data Binding with usercontrol object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, 2-way-object-databinding

I'm kinda new to data binding. I managed to do the one way databind but I have some trouble doing the two way one.

I made `1)`a usercontrol with some textblocks in it,
`2)`a class with some string properties,
`3)`an ObservableCollection that uses this class to generate the objects with those properties,`4)`a listview that generated by the ObservableCollection and that has the usercontrol as datatemplate for the items.

to bind a property of the class with a usercontrol's TextBlock I wrote the following code in XAML:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" Text="{Binding TextBlock_Property}" />
```

Where `MyTextBlock` is a textblock inside the usercontrol and `TextBlock_Property`is one of the properties from the class I created.
I also tried `Text="{Binding TextBlock_Property, Mode=TwoWay}"` but I didn't see any difference.

Note: When I change the property of a created object, the textblock changes too, but when I change the Textblock content the property doesn't update.

Update:The class I made is

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string TextBlock_Property { get; set; }

    public MyClass(string title, string textBlock_Property)
    {
        Title = title;
        TextBlock_Property = textBlock_Property;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My Dependency Property is only binding one way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027319/my-dependency-property-is-only-binding-one-way?rq=1)

Comment: W8 I'm going to search this Dependency property because not sure what it is, haven't used anything like that.

Comment: I don't think this is a dependency property issue.  It looks like he is just binding to a property.  Can we see the VM or code behind that has your properties?  And where you set your datacontext if you do?

Comment: yes give me some time to update the post

Comment: done I don't set any datacontext

Comment: @user2975038 what do you mean by _change the Textblock content_? `TextBlock` is read-only control and does not allow user input

Comment: I change it with code MyTextBlock.Text = "something";

Comment: so you remove binding which was there

Comment: Oups :S does that action remove the binding? :S
Then how could I do this action in a different way? (note that I change the usercontrol's Textblock when I tap it, and the code that changes that is in the usercontrol.

Comment: @user2975038 You should not be setting `TextBlock.Text = "Something"` when working with databound objects in WPF, you should be setting `MyClass.TextBlock_Property = "Something"` where `MyClass` is the datacontext for the TextBlock object and the source for the Text property binding

Comment: the problem is that I do this: `TextBlock.Text = "Something"` when a button that is in the usercontrol is pressed, so I do it from inside the usercontrol's code and I can't access MyClass's properties

Comment: so do you mean something like this?
`<TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" Text="{Binding TextBlock_Property, Mode=TwoWay}"   DataContext="MyClass"/>` Btw when I write `MyClass.` I only get 2 options to continue: 1)`Equals` and 2)`ReferenceEquals`

Answer (score 1):

The class `MyClass` has to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the property `TextBlock_Property` has signal a `OnPropertyChanged("TextBlock_Property")` event for the binding to be updated.

```
    private string _TextBlock_Property;

    public string TextBlock_Property
    {
        get { return _TextBlock_Property; }
        set { _TextBlock_Property = value; OnPropertyChanged("TextBlock_Property"); }
    }
```

---

To notify the Xaml/bound controls that data has changed one must implement `INotifyPropertyChange` on the class which holds the properties, and its instance is in the DataContext. Below is code I use to implement the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        /// <summary>
        /// Event raised when a property changes.
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Raises the PropertyChanged event.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property that has changed.</param>
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
}
```

---

To see this operation in its full, check out my blog article [Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding.](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017)

Comment: Can ou plz explain me the second part?
If I understood correctly the first part is to write this at the start:
    class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: I also get this error:
'Project_Name.MyClass' does not implement interface member 'System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged'

Comment: also when I write OnPropertyChanged it asks me to generate a method OnPropertyChanged() in order to be able to run.

Comment: @user2975038 See my edits on implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong but it still doesn't work :/
maybe it's because I have a clcik event in a button in usercontrol which changes `MyTextBlock.Text = "Something";` (just like @Rachel said in the comments) but I can't call this inside the usercontrol code: `MyClass.TextBlock_Property = "Something"`

Comment: @user2975038 how does the user control even know about the *instance* which was new'ed up called `MyClass`? How is the instance of the usercontrol passed to the UserControl?

Comment: I think I didn't say that right and caused some confusion. What I mean is that when the user clicks the button that I have in the UserControl , it changes the TextBlock that I have in the same UserControl named `MyTextBlock` but the `MyClass` property `TextBlock_Property` still doesn't get updated like I wanted.

Comment: Let's say I have `private ObservableCollection<MyClass> ObCo = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();` and I change `MyTextBlock.Text` (which is binded with MyClass's `TextBlock_Property`)  of `ObOC[0]` . The `TextBlock_Property` doesn't change when  `MyTextBlock.Text` changes.

Comment: @user2975038 The purpose of an Observable collection is to subscribe to change events (from the collection object itself) when something is added/removed from the collection. Items within the collection do not bubble up changes found on themselves. If you have this data inside a list to an instance, then the DataContext of the control or page must be assigned that instance. I surmise that the datacontext for the page or the control does not point to that `MyClass` instance.

Comment: So in my case do I just need to include this `DataContext="MyClass"` in the `MyTextblock` XAML or something more complictaed? Sorry for the many questions but I'm still trying to learn how all this works.

Comment: @user2975038 Binding happens via the `DataContext`. If the control doesn't have its context set, then it inherits its parent control's context. That occurs all the way to the top of the page's `DataContext` which is the root of all controls. Usually one binds the page's datacontext (see my example blog article) to the class instance `MyClass` and then one binds the controls datacontext to the  `TextBlock_Property` property.